# How to sort on nested field in graphql ruby?

Tags: ruby, graphql

How do I sort on a nested field (or a virtual attribute) in [graphql-ruby](https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby)?

```
ExampleType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
   name 'Example'
   description '...'
   field :nested_field, NestedType, 'some nested field' do
       // some result that is virtually calculated and returns
       OpenStruct.new(a: 123//some random number, b: 'some string')
   end
end

QueryType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
    name 'query'
    field: example, ExampleType do
    resolve -> (_obj, args,_ctx) {
            Example.find(args['id']) //Example is an active record
        }
    end

    field: examples, types[ExampleType] do
        resolve -> (_obj, args,_ctx) {
            // NOTE: How to order by nested field here? 
            Example.where(args['id'])
        }
    end
end
```

And if I am trying to get a list of examples ordered by `nested_field.a`:

```
query getExamples {
    examples(ids: ["1","2"], order: 'nested_field.a desc') {
        nested_field {
             a
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not order Active record by `virtual attribute`, because Active record can not match this `virtual attribute` to SQL/NoSQL query. You can avoid limitation, by **creating view at DB layer**. In GraphQL, sorting/pagination should be implemented at DB layer. Without that sorting/pagination implementation queries all data from DB to application memory.

Also, I want to recommend you switching from `order` argument with string type to `sort` argument with `[SearchSort!]` type based on enums. GraphQL schema will looks like that:

```
input SearchSort {
  sorting: Sorting!
  order: Order = DESC
}

enum Sorting {
  FieldName1
  FieldName2
}

enum Order {
  DESC
  ASC
}
```

It helps you implement mapping from GraphQL subquery to DataBase query.

Comment: I can't use the first suggestion because the order by nested_field is not an active record field. I don't understand the second suggestion. How does an enum help me sort on a virtual attribute when getting a list of `ExampleTypes`?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the problem with sorting by nesting field in Ruby Active Record.

Comment: "How does an enum help me sort" – GraphQL is typebased language. Using enums is better, then using string.

Comment: I change my answer. If you should move your nested_field to DB view, then you can use DB for sorting with active record.